# Internal energy and isobaric / isothermal process (ideal gas)

Tags: thermodynamics, energy

I'm currently working on one of my math problems and unfortunately, I don’t know how to get any further because our professor likes to add topics from physics and chemistry that have nothing to do with my studies. It would be great if someone could help me with how I have to calculate this problem.

I was given the following equations:
$dU=dQ+dW$ / $pV=nRT$ / $dW=-pdV$ / $dQ=-dW$ if dT=0, else $dQ=ncdT$

> U internal energy, Q heat transfer, W work, V volume, T temperature, p pressure, n amount of substance, R ideal gas constant and c specific heat capacity

and asked to:

> Calculate the change of the internal energy, if you first increase the temperature T1 to reach the state (p0;V’;T1) and subsequently at constant temperature compress / expand the system to the final state (p1;V1;T1).
> Repeat the calculation, but first change the pressure at constant temperature to p1 to get to the state (p1;V’’;T0) and from there reach the final state (p1;V1;T1) at constant pressure.

From my research, I know that the internal energy does not change during an isothermal process since $dU=dW+dQ=dW-dW=0$.

As the internal energy only changes during the isobaric process, I have to calculate 1) $(p_0,V_0,T_0)\rightarrow (p_0,V',T_1)$ and 2) $(p_0,V'',T_0)\rightarrow (p_1,V_1,T_1)$ and then compare the results.

Unfortunately, I have no clue how to calculate the change of internal energy during the isobaric process.
I am relatively sure that it has something to do with derivatives and integrals, since this is our current topic. But I couldn't find out anything more about it.
Can someone maybe give me some hints on how to do this calculation (I have no real knowledge of physics).
Thank you in advance and have a nice weekend!

Comment: For an ideal gas, internal energy depends only on temperature.  Since the change in temperature for both 1) and 2) is the same ($T_{1}-T_{o}$), the change in internal energy for 1) and 2) is the same.

Comment: In an isobaric process, dW=PdV, with P constant.